# Determine minimum OSX version a binary was compiled for

Tags: macos, toolchain, mach-o

When using Clang's or GCC's Darwin backends to create executables for OSX, the flag `-mmacosx-version-min=version` can be used to set the earliest version of OSX the executable will run on.

Is there any way to trace back from a given executable which flag was used to compile it? I.e. is there a way to determine which minimum OSX version is targeted by a given executable?

Comment: For the record, Apple haven’t contributed to GCC since its licence was changed to GPLv3. Whenever possible, use Clang/LLVM.

Comment: Short answer  `otool -l /path/to/bin | grep -E -A4 '(LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX|LC_BUILD_VERSION)' | grep -B1 sdk`; this also works with ARM64 machines like M1. `version` or `minos` gives the minimum supported macOS version, while `sdk` gives SDK version.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `otool -l /path/to/binary` and inspect the `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` load command; specifically, the version field.

For example, a binary compiled with the 10.8 SDK with deployment target (`-mmacosx-version-min`) 10.8 should have an `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` like this:

```
Load command 9
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.8
      sdk 10.8
```

whereas a binary compiled with the 10.8 SDK with deployment target 10.7 should have an `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` load command like this:

```
Load command 9
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.7
      sdk 10.8
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this information for static libraries (".a" files)?

Comment: This works also for static libraries (.a files). You'll see such load command per each object in the library. There's a nice UI application for Mac called 'MachOView" that allows comfortable browsing of binaries, and easy searching for these load commands.

Comment: wow, thanks! however, is there a way to find out this information with the stock tools built into macOS? 'otool' is part of the Developer Tools

Comment: is there a library or system api to do this programatically?

Comment: @electronic_coder Yes, there is an API to do it programmatically. Look at the source of otool (https://github.com/opensource-apple/cctools/tree/master/otool).

Comment: This is a great solution. I'm using it in my build scripts since a while. Unfortunately it seems that it doesn't work with arm64 (Apple Silicon) binaries. I'm using `otool -l -arch x86_64 /path/to/binary` to get the minimum version of my fat binary.

Answer (score 16):

The load command that is mentioned in the accepted answer is not listed when I build a modern macOS executable.  However `LC_BUILD_VERSION` does contain the `minos` and `sdk` fields:

```
Load command 10
      cmd LC_BUILD_VERSION
  cmdsize 32
 platform 1
    minos 11.0
      sdk 11.1
   ntools 1
     tool 3
  version 609.8
```

Comment: I noticed this too. See this screenshot with both types of output, from binaries that were built in the same CI run but by different tools (PyInstaller vs Rust): https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch/pull/544#issuecomment-751801675

Comment: The reason why you don't see the `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` is probably because your binary is for architecture arm64 or universal and you have an Apple Silicon Mac.
Note that in case of a universal binary the `minos` field does not necessarily reflect the actual minimum SDK if it is lower than 11.0. Use `otool -l -arch x86_64 /path/to/binary` for universal binaries.

Comment: Ah, it is true that I'm using Apple Silicon.

Comment: I'm not seeing it either, on intel with big sur

Comment: ok looks like if i build with CFLAGS=-mmacosx-version-min=10.10 I do see the LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX in the binary, and I lose LC_BUILD_VERSION

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to using `otool | grep` is to use `vtool` (available on macOS 10.15 and later).

For example:

```
❯ vtool -show-build ./test
test (architecture x86_64):
Load command 10
      cmd LC_BUILD_VERSION
  cmdsize 32
 platform MACOS
    minos 12.0
      sdk 12.3
   ntools 1
     tool LD
  version 764.0
test (architecture arm64):
Load command 10
      cmd LC_BUILD_VERSION
  cmdsize 32
 platform MACOS
    minos 12.0
      sdk 12.3
   ntools 1
     tool LD
  version 764.0
```

As noted in the comments, this does not work on static libraries or object files. From `man vtool`:

```
     Currently vtool only operates on final linked binaries, such as executable files, dynamic libraries, and bundles. Because the
     executable code in Mach-O final linked binaries cannot be moved or resized, and because the load commands reside between the mach
     header and the executable code, there is only a limited amount of space available for vtool to save changes. Set operations that
     add or resize load commands may fail if there isn't enough space in the Mach-O file availble to hold the new load commands.
```

`vtool` does, however, let you edit the build and source versions in the mach header, provided there is enough space for your revisions.

Comment: This seems not to work on static libraries, compared to the answers using `otool -l` that work for me with static libraries (on Intel, macOS 12.5, XCode 13).

Comment: Yes. This is documented in `man vtool`. Apologies for omitting it from my answer. In exchange, you get the ability to set or remove the relevant load commands, provided enough space in the mach header.

Comment: This is better than looking at `LC_BUILD_VERSION` in `otool` output, because `vtool` decodes the `platform` and `tool` numbers into human-readable strings.