# Determining OS X SDK and Deployment Target versions from Framework

Tags: xcode, macos, otool

Fairly straightforward question - if I have a `.framework` file, is there a command/tool that can be used to determine the SDK and Deployment Target versions used to create the framework?

Similarly, can this be performed on the application binary stored inside a .app file? I'm looking to automate a script that will go search a list of previously-built apps/frameworks, without having the original `.xcodeproj` files, and determining their high/low supported OS versions.

Comment: Related: [Determine minimum OSX version a binary was compiled for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17143373/183120)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To find out the SDK and Deployment Target of some binary you should explore the LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX load command. Use `otool -l <some_binary>` to see load commands.

Example:

```
$otool -l my_binary
...
Load command 9
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.7
      sdk 10.8
...

$otool -l /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/CoreWLAN 
...
Load command 8
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.8
      sdk 10.8
...
```

Example with piping to `grep`:

```
otool -l my_binary | grep -A 3 LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
```

Comment: *Perfect.* I had played around with `otool`, but the flags were dauntingly numerous. My framework was indeed built with both `version` and `sdk` set to 10.8, and I can now confirm that changing the (Compiler Default) to 10.7 produces a better copy.

Comment: Any tips on doing the same for iOS? Been trying to determine the deployment target of the current Facebook and Crashlytics frameworks used in a project, but this command does not show anything like a min version.

Comment: @Clafou sorry, can't help you in that

Comment: @Clafou are you still looking on how to do it for iOS?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian not anymore, but if you have a solution it would still be useful to share it!

Comment: @Clafou the solution is basically the same but you need to get a suite of cross compiler tools, you can get it by folllowing instructions here: http://hyegar.com/2016/02/22/ios-cross-compiler/ and then doing `armv7-apple-darwin11-otool -l ios_binary | grep -A 3 LC_VERSION`

Comment: It works for iOS provided you tell it the arch: `otool -arch armv7 -l libfoo.a`.

Comment: thanks! however, is there a way to find out the 'Deployment Target' with the stock tools built into macOS? 'otool' is part of the Developer Tools

Comment: In my case I needed to swap out `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` with `LC_BUILD_VERSION`, but otherwise this answer worked great.

Comment: I got it to work under Linux with `7z x file.dmg` and `llvm-otool -arch x86-64 -l <binary file> | grep -A 7 LC_BUILD_VERSION`. The output contains a line starting with `minos`

Answer (score 6):

On Big Sur 11.4 I check with:

```
otool -l my_binary | grep minos
```

Output for example:

```
minos 11.0
```