# How to check a lib (static or dynamic) is built for iOS simulator or Mac OSX

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

My work is blocked by 'ld: warning: URGENT: building for iOS simulator, but linking in object file built for OSX' or vice versa, so I want to find out which platform a lib was built for.

I tried:

```
file tmp/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib
lipo -info tmp/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib
otool -hv -arch all tmp/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a
otool -hv -arch all /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a
```

and only thing I got is CPU type x86_64 or i386.

Answer (score 1):

As originally described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17148833/4797324) post, you can run `otool -l /path/to/binary` and inspect output for 'Load' commands. Output should contain `LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS` command for iOS binaries, and `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` for macOS.

Answer (score 1):

use command otool to find the `platform` value:

```
otool -l libyuv_neon.a | grep -i platform
 platform 2
 platform 2
 platform 2
otool -l libyuv_neon.a | grep -i platform
 platform 7
 platform 7
 platform 7
 platform 7
```

Platform 2 is for iPhone, and platform 7 is for simulator.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `vtool` with `-show-build` it will tell you the platform the binary is targeting.

```
% vtool -show-build foobar.dylib 
build/layers/foobar.dylib:
Load command 8
      cmd LC_BUILD_VERSION
  cmdsize 32
 platform IOS
    minos 13.0
      sdk 17.0
   ntools 1
     tool LD
  version 1015.7
```

Currently vtool only operates on final linked binaries, such as executable files, dynamic libraries, and bundles.